# how to run wget from bash or script file?

Tags: bash, url, terminal, wget

I am trying to run the following **wget** command with its parameters from a Script file (sh), but it won't run. However, if I run the same command on a terminal or console, it runs as expected. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

GetMyUrls.sh

```
URL="http://craigslist.com"
wget -q ${URL} -O - | tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:[^"]\+"' | sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g' > myurls.txt
```

**EDIT:**
If I run the following command directly in the terminal, it works and the output is shown below the code.

```
wget -q http://craigslist.com -O - |     tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' |     grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:[^"]\+"' |     sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g' > myurls.txt
```

output:

```
baby-jesus@babyjesus-X501A1:~$ wget -q http://craigslist.com -O - |     tr       "\t\r\n'" '   "' |     grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:      [^"]\+"' |     sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g'
https://post.craigslist.org/c/pit
https://accounts.craigslist.org/login/home
https://www.craigslist.org/about/sites
https://post.craigslist.org/c/pit
https://accounts.craigslist.org/login/home
https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/
https://www.craigslist.org/about/scams
https://www.craigslist.org/about/safety
https://www.craigslist.org/about/privacy.policy   
https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/system-status
https://www.craigslist.org/about/ 
https://www.craigslist.org/about/craigslist_is_hiring
https://www.craigslist.org/about/open_source
http://blog.craigslist.org/
https://www.craigslist.org/about/best/all/
https://www.youtube.com/user/craigslist
http://www.craigslistjoe.com/
http://craigconnects.org/
https://forums.craigslist.org/?areaID=33
https://forums.craigslist.org/?areaID=33&amp;forumID=5178
https://forums.craigslist.org/?areaID=33&amp;forumID=3232
```

All I want to do is simply do exactly the same but from Script file and direct the output to a text file by adding at the end of that string **> myurls.txt**

Comment: Could you please first check if `wget` alone only is running or not? If it is running then it means other following commands are responsible for not showing output(may be they are not getting exact match of strings etc)? Let us know.

Comment: To debug your bash script try adding the commands “which wget” and “set -x” before your command. This should show you if wget is in the path and what command will run before it runs them.oh and echo $path

Comment: @ThN, kindly paste output/samples in text format in your post, images/screen shots are not recommended to post on SO.

Comment: Did you try `curl` instead of `wget` already?

Comment: @Thomas not yet, but would be kind enough to show me how I can do the same with curl. I've been looking around on the internet about curl and I don't understand it. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't run`? What is the exact error message you receive?

Comment: @jhnc Well, it runs with no error, but there is nothing in the output file.

Comment: If you edit your script by (1) delete all `|` and (2) prepend `echo` to the wget commandline, and then run it, does the file contain anything? If you add the command `ls -l myurls.txt` before and after the wget line, what does it show?